# How to validate an OAuth2 access token (JWT) without accessing the auth server

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt

Trying to understand the 2-legged client credentials scheme in OAuth2. Some people state that JWT is great format for Access Token because it is self-contained and resource server doesn't need to verify the token from the authorization server (STS). But how is this done? The only way I see the resource server could itself validate the JWT is by storing a public key on the server, which is used to verify the signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a JWT as an access token, the Resource Server doesn't need to call out to the Authorization Server to verify it. Indeed the Resource Server will need to store the public key of the Authorization Server to do so. Obtaining that public key is an out-of-band process.

Verification of a JWT consists of checking the signature plus some additional checks on claims embedded in the token e.g. timestamps (`iat`, `exp`, `nbf`) and identifiers (`aud`).

The advantage of JWT over other forms of signed data/tokens is that JWTS are standardized and flexible wrt. cryptography used by them which makes it possible to use standard libraries to create/verify them instead of having to write custom code.

Comment: Sure. I just want to clarify if you in fact answered my question or not :) So you mean that 1) JWT is self-contained in the case when public key is used on the resource server? So there is not other 'magic' involved here, the JWT token content is verified through the public key. 2) why is this special to JWT only? You can use a public key in any other case too...

Comment: added some text on those topics