# How can a resource server validate an access token without the authorization server

Tags: jwt

I'm learning about access tokens and refresh tokens. I understand...

- An access token is an artifact that proves the user has been authorized to access a resource and allows a client application to perform specific actions on behalf of the user.
- A refresh token is an artifact that lets a client application get new access tokens without having to ask the user to log in again.

I don't understand the following paragraph from [this JWT book](https://auth0.com/resources/ebooks/jwt-handbook):

> The key aspect of the separation between access and refresh tokens lies in the possibility of making access tokens easy to validate. An access token that carries a signature (such as a signed JWT) may be validated by the resource server on its own. There is no need to contact the authorization server for this purpose. Refresh tokens, on the other hand, require access to the authorization server.

The text is referring to the following image:

[image]

What exactly does "validate" mean here? How can the resource server validate the access token on its own? If the authorization server generates the access token, which it does in this case, isn't the authorization server required to validate the access token?

The only thing I can think of is that the resource server has a copy of the key used to sign the access token (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215392/6611672)). If so, doesn't that render the authorization server redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Web Tokens can be validated because, as you guess correctly, the resource server will have beforehand the public key of the private key that was used to sign that token. It means, that if someone in the middle tried to tamper the JWT, the validation will fail and the JWT should not be processed.

Also, the JWT contains fields as the expiration time that can be checked by the resource to understand if the token is still valid or not.